# Multiple wp.editor in a custom widget using JQuery

Tags: customization, widgets, wp-editor

Hi I'm trying to build a custom accordion widget with the possibility to add multiples panels with WYSIWYG editor. My issue is that the editor content from the javascript is not saved in my widget $instance. Here's my code :

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-panel", function (e) {
        
        var editor_id = content_id + uniqid() ;
        var panel = $('<div class="accordion-panel">' +
            '<input class="widefat panel-title" type="text" ' +
            'name="' + title_name +'" />' +
            '<textarea class="widefat panel-content" id="'+ editor_id +'" ' +
            'name="' + content_name +'" ></textarea>' +
            '</div>');
       
       panel.appendTo('.accordion-panels');
      
        wp.editor.initialize(editor_id, {
            tinymce: {
                wpautop: true,
                toolbar1: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist | blockquote hr wp_more | alignleft aligncenter alignright | link unlink | fullscreen | wp_adv',
                toolbar2: 'formatselect alignjustify forecolor | pastetext removeformat charmap | outdent indent | undo redo | wp_help'
            },
            quicktags: true,
            mediaButtons: true
        });
    });
```

And the widget form function :

```
<script>
            
            var content_name = "<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'panels' ); ?>[content][]" ;
            var title_name = "<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'panels' ); ?>[title][]" ;
            var content_id = "<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'panels' ) . '-content-'; ?>" ;
            </script>
        <div class="accordion-panels">
       
            <?php
            if ( ! empty( $panels ) ) {
                foreach ( $panels as $panel ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="accordion-panel">
                        <input class="widefat panel-title" type="text" 
                            name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'panels' ); ?>[title][]" 
                            value="<?php echo esc_attr( $panel['title'] ); ?>" />
                        <?php
                        $content_id = $this->get_field_id( 'panels' ) . '-content-' . uniqid();
                        wp_editor( $panel['content'], $content_id );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <p>
            <button class="add-panel button"><?php _e('Add Panel','a2c_widget') ; ?></button>
        </p>
       <?php                
        }
```

and my debug infos

```
  [04-Jul-2023 14:39:59 UTC] Array
    (
        [title] => titre du widget
        [panels] => Array
            (
                [title] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => titre
                    )
    
                [content] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )
    
            )
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my 'update' function in the widget

```
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            
            $instance = array();
            $instance = $old_instance;
            // Sanitize and save the widget title
            if ( isset( $new_instance['title'] ) ) {
                $instance['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );
            }
        
            // Save the accordion panels
            if ( isset( $new_instance['panels'] ) && is_array( $new_instance['panels'] ) ) {
                $panels = array();
        
                // Sanitize and save each panel title and content
                foreach ( $new_instance['panels']['title'] as $index => $title ) {
                    $panel = array(
                        'title'   => sanitize_text_field( $title ),
                        'content' => wp_kses_post( $new_instance['panels']['content'][ $index ] ),
                    );
        
                    // Only add the panel if both title and content are provided
                    if ( ! empty( $panel['title'] ) && ! empty( $panel['content'] ) ) {
                        $panels[] = $panel;
                    }
                }
        
                $instance['panels'] = $panels;
            }
        
            return $instance;
            
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your widget is meant to know what the content is if you're giving it a unique ID on the javascript side using `editor_id = content_id + uniqid()`, how would it know that ID on the PHP side? I also see that your save function is missing from your question, so if the problem is there then there's no way to know, can you add the full code?

Comment: Tanks for your answer. The content_id is from the widget side 'var content_id = "<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'panels' ) . '-content-'; ?>" ;'  I add a uniqid() on javascript side to allow multiple panels. But, you're right, there's a way to get the editor ID in the widget?

Comment: it was a comment/clarifying question, can you edit your question to include the save function for your widget? Your question is missing important information

Comment: just edit my question with the save/update function